# Query on timestamps to select only recent rows for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that records users answers for a number of questions:

**tableA**

```
user_id  | question_id | date answered | correct?
-------------------------------------------------
   66         345          timestamp        1
   34         654          timestamp        0
   34         654          timestamp        1
```

Every question attempt by every user is stored in the database.

I then also have a list of categories and the question_ids that go in that category. e.g

**tableB**

```
category_id    |    question_id
--------------------------------
   1                     34
   1                     44
   1                     23
   2                     99 
   2                     44
```

I am trying to write a query to work out the percentage of questions in the category that the user has previously answered correctly (where `correct? = 1`) and also the percentage of questions correct of the last 20 questions answered in the category.

So far I can do the first part, but not the second

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(*), COUNT(correct?)
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB USING (question_id)
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP_BY category_id
```

this gives me the number of questions in total in the category and the number of questions the user has answered correctly in the category. Something like this

```
cat_id  | total_questions | answered_correctly
-------------------------------------------------
 1           455               323
 2           334               123
```

However, for each category, I also want to look at the last 20 questions answered in a category and retrieve the number that were correct. So I want something like this:

```
cat_id | total_questions | answered_correctly   | questions_correct_in_last_20_answered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1           455                323                            12
 2           334                123                            8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add last twenty questions answered, you need pick last twenty rows and then count the correct answers, but `GROUP BY` and `LIMIT` don't go so well together and you can't attach the last twenty rows unless you are checking for only one category at a time. MySQL doesn't allow you to join a table when one of the subquery is referencing the table being joined on.

So the below query is a workaround to which gets all answers for the category sorted on timestamp, makes a list, takes first twenty and then counts the number of correct answers. Tricky, but gets the job done.

```
SELECT category_id,
       Total_Q_Tried,
       Total_Unique_Q_Tried,
       Total_Answered_Correctly,
       Total_Answered_Correctly / Total_Q_Tried*100 Total_Correct_Answer_Percentage,
       Total_Answered_Correctly_In_Last20,
       Total_Answered_Correctly_In_Last20 / LEAST(20,Total_Q_Tried)*100 Total_Correct_Answer_Last20_Percentage
FROM (
   SELECT
     B.category_id, COUNT(B.question_id) Total_Q_Tried, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT B.question_id) Total_Unique_Q_Tried,
     SUM(A.correct) Total_Answered_Correctly,

     (SELECT length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(AA.correct ORDER BY AA.date_answered DESC SEPARATOR ',' ), ',', 20))
           - length(replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(AA.correct ORDER BY AA.date_answered DESC SEPARATOR ',' ), ',', 20),'1', ''))
      FROM tableA AA INNER JOIN tableB BB ON AA.question_id = BB.question_id
      WHERE BB.category_id = B.category_id
           AND AA.user_id = A.user_id
     ) Total_Answered_Correctly_In_Last20

    FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B
          ON B.question_id = A.question_id
    WHERE A.user_id = 34
    GROUP BY B.category_id ) FinalNumbers
```

If you want percentage of correct answers in last twenty, you would need to use smaller of 20 and `TOTAL_Q_TRIED` and `TOTAL_ANSWERED_CORRECTLY_IN_LAST20` as calculated in the query.

--

I couldn't try, but performance might not be good if there are lots and lots of rows.

```
| USER_ID | QUESTION_ID |                  DATE_ANSWERED | CORRECT |
|---------|-------------|--------------------------------|---------|
|      66 |           1 | January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |
|      34 |           1 | January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |
|      34 |           2 | January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |
|      34 |           3 | January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       0 |
|      34 |           4 | January, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |
|      34 |           6 | January, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       0 |


| CATEGORY_ID | QUESTION_ID |
|-------------|-------------|
|           1 |           1 |
|           2 |           2 |
|           2 |           3 |
|           2 |           4 |
|           2 |           5 |
|           3 |           6 |


| CATEGORY_ID | TOTAL_Q_TRIED | TOTAL_UNIQUE_Q_TRIED | TOTAL_ANSWERED_CORRECTLY | TOTAL_CORRECT_ANSWER_PERCENTAGE | TOTAL_ANSWERED_CORRECTLY_IN_LAST20 | TOTAL_CORRECT_ANSWER_LAST20_PERCENTAGE |
|-------------|---------------|----------------------|--------------------------|---------------------------------|------------------------------------|----------------------------------------|
|           1 |             1 |                    1 |                        1 |                             100 |                                  1 |                                    100 |
|           2 |             3 |                    3 |                        2 |                         66.6667 |                                  2 |                                66.6667 |
|           3 |             1 |                    1 |                        0 |                               0 |                                  0 |                                      0 |
```

---

Per comment below - add total of unique questions answered correctly.

This gets tougher and tougher. I'm joining on every column including the timestamp in the latest query added to get the unique answers. See below.

```
SELECT category_id,
       Total_Q_Tried,
       Total_Unique_Q_Tried,
       Total_Answered_Correctly,
       Total_Unique_Answered_Correctly,
       Total_Answered_Correctly / Total_Q_Tried*100 Total_Correct_Answer_Percentage,
       Total_Answered_Correctly_In_Last20,
       Total_Answered_Correctly_In_Last20 / LEAST(20,Total_Q_Tried)*100 Total_Correct_Answer_Last20_Percentage
FROM (
  SELECT
     B.category_id, COUNT(B.question_id) Total_Q_Tried, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT B.question_id) Total_Unique_Q_Tried,
     SUM(A.correct) Total_Answered_Correctly,
     SUM(UniqueA.correct) Total_Unique_Answered_Correctly,


     (SELECT length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(AA.correct ORDER BY AA.date_answered DESC SEPARATOR ',' ), ',', 20))
           - length(replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(AA.correct ORDER BY AA.date_answered DESC SEPARATOR ',' ), ',', 20),'1', ''))
      FROM tableA AA INNER JOIN tableB BB ON AA.question_id = BB.question_id
      WHERE BB.category_id = B.category_id
           AND AA.user_id = A.user_id
     ) Total_Answered_Correctly_In_Last20

  FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B
        ON B.question_id = A.question_id
       LEFT JOIN (select user_id, question_id,  MAX(date_answered) date_answered, correct
                    from tableA
                    GROUP BY user_id, question_id, correct
                   ) UniqueA
        ON A.user_id = UniqueA.user_id AND A.question_id = UniqueA.question_id AND  A.date_answered = UniqueA.date_answered
  WHERE A.user_id = 34
  GROUP BY B.category_id ) FinalNumbers;
```

This might not work out right for the % for last 20 questions answered correctly. Please test it out. If it doesn't replace, the `tableA A` and `tableA AA` with the `UniqueA`'s select query to work on only unique answers and remove the latest left join added.

Comment: updated. please check. Note that you should be able to understand the query and modify the `SELECT` calculations to get the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Hei, Friend look this:

> Foo.c SELECT, COUNT (*) AS pct * t.factor   FROM foo   JOIN (SELECT
>   100/COUNT (*) FROM foo AS factor) AS t   GROUP BY foo.c;

Ooops! So it was enough to make a JOIN to get the number of total users, and apply some math test.
  Returning to my situation practical-metaphorical, we have:

```
SELECT count (id) AS pct * t.factor, good_person FROM people
  JOIN (SELECT 100/COUNT (*) FROM persons AS factor) AS t
  GROUP BY good_person;
```

the original link (in portuguese), here: [MySQL Blog](http://danielneis.wordpress.com/2008/02/08/mysql-e-porcentagens/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a subquery returning the `LIMIT 20` sorted by timestamp.